# Use .js file in browser and in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Can I include some javascript file (test.js situated in public folder) both in the browser file (someBrowserFile.js) and in the node.js backend file (someBackendFile.js):

## test.js:

```
function use(name) {
    console.log("I can use" + name);
}
```

## someBrowserFile.js:

```
import * as lib from './test.js';

lib.use("test module");
```

## someBackendFile.js:

```
var lib = require("./public/test.js");

lib.use("test module");
```

Because with node I have to use "module.exports" and with ES6 - "export {use};". If I use ES6 syntax node will throw SyntaxError and if I use "module.exports" then it won't work in the browser.
So is there a general syntax to use so I could include my file in the browser and in node.

Comment: this the same question I'm asking myself. Unfortunately I do not see a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly, no.

But we usually use bundlers and preprocessors that allow this. Take a look into [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) which are usually used alongside [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Thanks. I know about bundlers but I was hoping that I would be able to solve this problem simpler :(

Comment: @PetroKoval At first, I also thought bundlers were too much, but I encourage you to take a look, they aren't that bad... (:

Answer (score 1):

For using ES6 in NodeJs you would have to try using "babel" or some other kind of interpreter

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this now, you can use "type"="module" in package.json to use es6 imports in Node